# How do I tell MS Word to email using GMail and NOT Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-word, gmail

When you have a document open and select Send, Email as attachment, MS Word defaults to Outlook.  I have not used Outlook for a long time and I have changed all my default email clients to be GMail.  However, I can't find where to do it for MS Word.  Can anyone please help me with this?

Please do not tell me to open my Gmail and attach the document.  I know how to do that.  I want to be able to email *directly* from within Word.

Comment: Not sure how you've set your "default email clients", but Gmail may not be the actual default mail handler. To fix this, follow the directions in [this Google support doc](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966). (Not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure if it actually works. If it does, please tell me and I'll post it as an answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately that doesn't actually work.  I have already done that bit and if I email from the web it will default to GMail.  It is just from within MS Word. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To do this from within Word or other Windows programs, or by right-clicking a file in explorer and choosing Send to -> Mail recipient, you need a MAPI client to intercept such requests.  One such client is [tvhgooglemapi](https://code.google.com/p/tvhgooglemapi/):

> Tvhgooglemapi is a simple tool that pretends to be a real mail client to windows but really only uploads the mail to the drafts folder of gmail and then opens the draft in the default webbrowser. For the user this is almost exactly the same as having the gmail web interface as the default mailclient for some windows applications

You'll need to have Java installed for it to work, and IMAP enabled in your Gmail account.

By the way, when I first ran it, the window prompting for my Gmail login credentials (my Gmail address and my application-specific password) was hidden under other active windows, but a couple of <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> later, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

tvhgooglemapi is sadly no longer supported. If you are looking for an alternative, you might want to look into Affixa. It's free for private use.
Hope this helps future users

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).